# Fallback error on css image-set property with Edge

Tags: css, sass, microsoft-edge

i have a problem with image-set property when i use it with an avif file as first option to render in Microsoft Edge. The fallback doesn't work( as you know, Edge doesn't support avif type yet ) and Edge load the avif file even if can't support it. Is there a way to make the fallback works properly??
Note: I am using autoprefixer in my gulp file so it isn't a prefix problem.

`.speaker__imagen { background-image: url(../img/bg_1.png); background-image: image-set( url(../img/bg_1.avif) 1x, url(../img/bg_1.webp) 1x, url(../img/bg_1.png) 1x ); }` 
I want to leave the image-set property without taking off the avif option from the render option's list

Comment: have you tried ```<img onerror="this.src = something"```

Comment: Saddly it doesn't work either because the loading triggers a 200 status so there is no error

Comment: Use pseudo element and set image in content property.

Comment: Nope, not working, Edge also shows the 200 status but wrongly implemented. Thank you anyway

Comment: Hi @NicolasTabia, does my answer offer some help? If you have further questions, feel free to share with us.

Answer (score 0):

The fallback is the "fallback" to `image-set`/`-webkit-image-set`, so apparently it does not work if `image-set`/`-webkit-image-set` works even though `.avif` is not supported in Edge. Interestingly, Edge and Chrome share the same prefix `-webkit` so you'll have to treat them as the same.

Actually, you can [use `type()` to provide alternative image formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image/image-set#using_image-set_to_provide_alternative_image_formats), which should work in a more favorable way than `background-image: url()` as the fallback. However, `type()` has not been supported on Chrome and Edge yet since in the [doc](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5432024223449088) they said :

> our implementation has not been per the spec, as only URL values were
> accepted for the image, and only resolutions with 'x' as a unit were
> accepted.

Additionally, Edge's support for `.avif` may be on the way because we have a new command line flag `--enable-features=msEdgeAVIF` on Edge Canary, which means the Dev Team may have been testing the implementation.